Bash MySQL Looping through results
I'm trying to read MySQL results via a loop. I have this working but I have a small issue.
The code I'm using is
while IFS=$'\t' read fieldA fieldB fieldC fieldD; do

    echo "$fieldA $fieldB $fieldC $fieldD"

done < <(mysql -N -u $mysql --password=$pass database -h $host -e "SELECT BLAB BLABBLAB BLABBLAB BLAB")

If one of the fields is empty then the variable is populated with the value from the next field.
eg:
if fieldC is empty echo $feildC will show the results from fieldD
if fieldB and fieldC are empty echo $feildB will show the results from fieldD
How do I account for the empty fields ? I was hoping the variable would return null or blank.
Thanks
UPDATE
This is working using :
while IFS=$'|' read fieldA fieldB fieldC fieldD; do

    echo "$fieldA $fieldB $fieldC $fieldD"

done < <(mysql -N -u $mysql --password=$pass database -h $host -e "SELECT BLAB BLABBLAB BLABBLAB BLAB" | tr '\t' '|' )


please update the question with a sampte set of data from the mysql call, making sure to include a couple lines that display your issue; also update the question with the expected results

if you only have 3 values are you 100% sure this is due to fieldC being empty? could any of the other fields be empty instead? same question when 2 values are empty ... are you 100% sure it will always be fieldB and fieldC that are empty, or could the other fields be empty instead? addressing the empty fields is (relatively) easy to do if we have a programmatic means of knowing which field(s) is empty

@markp-fuso fieldB could be empty, the other fields will always be populated.

@markp-fuso I'll create an example in the morning and update with the data. Thanks

see the (duplicate) link; gist of the issue is that consecutive white space delimiters (space, tab) with no intervening data is processed (by bash) as a single delimiter ... get fancy with mapfile or replace the tabs with a non-white space character that you know doesn't exist in the data (eg, replace \t with :) and then use IFS=':' read ...;  does mysql allow you to designate an output delimiter? if not, use tr (or sed) to change the delimiter; alternatively, use a tool (eg, awk) that can recognize empty fields between white space delimiters

See --batch or -B option in mysql man page.

@markp-fuso thanks for the link and advise. I now have this working. I'll post how.
